# Get List of functions (with metrics) in My Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reflection, code-metrics, lines-of-code, line-count

I have a large assembly (written in VB.NET).

Is there a simple way (or tool) that will list all the functions with perhaps the size of each function (in respect to lines of code)?

I have downloaded nDepend but could not see that facility within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NDepend you just have to do: *NDepend > Search > Search Method by Size.*

[image: NDepend Search Method by Size]

Notice that you can export this result to HTML, XML, txt, Excel.

Notice that a C# LINQ query is generated and you can edit it to refine it and eventually append more code metrics:

[image: NDepend list method code metrics]

Notice also you can list methods according to more criterias than size:

[image: NDepend Search criterias]